# How to test if my method throws an observable error in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, angular2-testing

I am creating unit-testcases for my angular2 components.

so far test cases are running correctly.

but I am facing issues regarding my asynchronous calls.

For ex. I have following method for creating new user which throws an error if user is already present :

```
onSubmit():Observable<any> {  
    this._userService.saveUser(this.user).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this._directoryService.getDirectoryById(this.selectedDirectory._id).subscribe(
            (directory) => {                        
              this.users = directory[0].users;
            },
            (error) => {              
              return error;              
            }
          );
        },
        (error) => {                   
          return error;         
        }
     );
    return ;
}
```

In my service , I have am throwing an error using following:

```
if (alreadyExist) {
        let error = "user already exist in database";
        return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

Now I am expecting this method to throw an error:

```
expect( function(){ app.onSubmit(); } )
    .toThrow(new Error("User already exist in database"));
```

Now from my understanding , this test case should be successful , but I am getting below error after my test case fails:

> Expected function to throw an exception.

I tried multiple expect blocks:

```
expect(app.onSubmit()).toThrowError(new Error("User already exist in database"));
```

but still not getting any success.

any inputs?

thanks

Answer (score 29):

The thing about `Observable.throw` is that it doesn't actually throw any error. Even if it did, it would be handled internally. `expect().toThrowError` only catches exceptions that aren't handle and that bubble up to the test.

What `Observable.throw` does instead is pass the error to the `onError` callback. So what you should do instead is subscribe the call, and check the error in the callback

```
it('..', async(() => {
  app.onSubmit().subscribe(
    () => {
      fail('expected error');
    },
    (error) => {
      expect(error).toBe('user already exist in database');
    });
}))
```

Comment: tried this... but its saying that one of my instance variable is undefined..thought I have initialised it as app.edit=false.error is: `cannot read property edit of undefined`. @peeskillet

Comment: Can you post a _complete, minimal_ test the reproduces the problem

Comment: The `fail()` function is not officially supported by Jest anymore.